# Reclassify thousands of values with no pattern in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, reclassify

I have a raster file with pixel values between 11010 and 812210 and I would like to change all these values in integers between 0 and 5. The problem here is that there is no pattern that I can use (at least not obvious to me) to reclassify this values with logical expressions and I have more than 2000 combinations. Is there any way to make a reclassification, maybe with a CSV file or something?

This values were gotten with the **.expression** function in GEE with ESA Land Cover and Potentials Ecosystems Data.

I´m sorry that I can´t give you any sample code but here there is an example of the combinations that I must to get.

[image]

Any idea on to solve this problem? Or even a confirmation that I should write more than 2000 lines of code with **.map** function jeje.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [upload the CSV](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/table_upload#upload-a-csv-file) file as a FeatureCollection asset you should be able to use it as a lookup table to supply the `ee.Image.remap` function with from-to reclassification pairs.

Before you upload the CSV file, rename the desired columns as "from" and "to". Once the CSV is uploaded, you can use either of the following options to fetch the "from" and "to" columns for input to `ee.Image.remap`.

Pseudo code:

**Using `ee.Reducer.toList()`**

```js
var fromToFc = ee.FeatureCollection('users/<username>/<fromToFc>');

var propNames = ee.List(['from', 'to']);
var fromToList = ee.List(
  fromToFc.reduceColumns({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.toList().repeat(propNames.size()),
    selectors: propNames
  })
  .get('list')
);

var from = fromToList.get(0);
var to = fromToList.get(1);

var yourImg = ee.Image('users/<username>/<yourImg>');
var reclassedImg = yourImg.remap(from, to, null, '<BandName>');
```

**Using `ee.FeatureCollection.aggregate_array`**

```js
var fromToFc = ee.FeatureCollection('users/<username>/<fromToFc>');

var from = fromToFc.aggregate_array('from');
var to = fromToList.aggregate_array('to');

var yourImg = ee.Image('users/<username>/<yourImg>');
var reclassedImg = yourImg.remap(from, to, null, '<BandName>');
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation, it is really clear and it works very well. Before I read your message I wrote all the combinations in the console and with **ee.Reducer.toList()** I got the same results. Awesome @JustinBraaten

Answer (score 0):

Can you rank order the pixel values and then reclassify using 5/2000 (0.0025) increments?

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. I can´t change the pixel values because they are not equally spaced. In addition, each value tells me three features of the pixel. For example the pixel value 32150 is because the pixel have the ecosystem 3, with transformation in the year of study (2), and the ESA Land cover code 150. @JustinBraaten answered with two interest ways to solve this problem. Thank you so much :)